# How do I plot the data I have in a horizontal bar graph with descending values so that all the names of the states appear?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot the following data:

```
         Alabama               Alaska              Arizona 
            5471                 1349                 2328 
        Arkansas           California             Colorado 
            2842                16306                 3201 
     Connecticut             Delaware District of Columbia 
            3067                 1685                 3195 
         Florida              Georgia               Hawaii 
           15029                 8925                  289 
           Idaho             Illinois              Indiana 
             661                17556                 5852 
            Iowa               Kansas             Kentucky 
            2517                 2145                 4157 
       Louisiana                Maine             Maryland 
            8103                  907                 5798 
   Massachusetts             Michigan            Minnesota 
            5981                 6136                 2408 
     Mississippi             Missouri              Montana 
            3599                 6631                  638 
        Nebraska               Nevada        New Hampshire 
            1651                 1952                  964 
      New Jersey           New Mexico             New York 
            5387                 1645                 9712 
  North Carolina         North Dakota                 Ohio 
            8739                  573                10244 
        Oklahoma               Oregon         Pennsylvania 
            3455                 2286                 8929 
    Rhode Island       South Carolina         South Dakota 
             895                 6939                  544 
       Tennessee                Texas                 Utah 
            7626                13577                 1072 
         Vermont             Virginia           Washington 
             472                 5949                 3434 
   West Virginia            Wisconsin              Wyoming 
            1575                 4787                  494
```

In a horizontal bar graph with descending values. I tried various plots, but the names of the states do not appear. Only some names are printed.

I have used the simple Plot function, but I am unable to figure out how to get the names of the states to appear.

### Plotting the above data in a horizontal histogram

```
plot(table(dfnew$state), type = "h")
```

Only a few names of the states appear.

Comment: could you `dput` your data, so that it is easy to use ?

Comment: Hi Denis. Sorry I did not put the data. That data was actually an output of another command, which I haven't figured out how to get into a data frame yet. However, the answer below helped me immensely.

Comment: @KaustubhMulay  You don't exactly need a data.frame to get us the data. It would be good enough to type `dput(table(dfnew$state))` and paste the result of that into your question.   That will make it easier next time you have a question.

Comment: @G5W Thanks for that as well. Will remember that!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start with `arrange()` from the `dplyr` package to get values in descending order:

```
data %>% arrange(desc(value))
```

Then use `ggplot2`'s `geom_bar` along with `coord_flip`, which will give you the horizontal bars. Try something like this:

```
 ggplot(data, aes(x=state, y=value)) +
 geom_bar() +
 coord_flip()
```

Comment: `arrange(desc(state))` orders the data by name of state but not by value as requested.

Answer (score 2):

While I see that you tried to provide your data (Thank you), it is not in a format that I can use without typing it all in again. I don't want to do that, so I will use the built-in USArrests data instead.

You can get a horizontal bar graph using the `barplot` function. Trying to squeeze 50 states in there, you will need to adjust the margins and use small print, but it certainly can be done. You can use `order` to sort the entries.

```
data(USArrests)

par(mar=c(4,7,1,2))
barplot(USArrests$Murder[order(USArrests$Murder)], 
    names.arg=row.names(USArrests)[order(USArrests$Murder)],
    las=2, cex.names=0.7, horiz=TRUE)
```

[image: Horizontal bar plot]

I *think* that what you need for your data is

```
par(mar=c(4,7,1,2))
TAB = table(dfnew$state)
barplot(sort(TAB), names.arg=names(TAB)[order(TAB)],
    las=2, cex.names=0.7, horiz=TRUE)
```

but without your data, that is untested.  BTW, you may also need to make your graphics window bigger than the default.

Comment: Thanks a log G5W. The solution that you gave worked. I will look into making the graphics window bigger. Thanks again.